# regex to find text followed by space or (

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract a few words (as shown in expected output) from the following sample.log. I am facing difficulty in extracting the last expected output (ie, xuvs). The code can extract all outputs except the last.I am trying to find how to code regex to imply "find text followed by space or (". Any pointers to other approaches is much appreciated.

**sample.log**

```
  for (i=0; i< models; i = i+1) begin:modelgen

 model_ip model_inst
     (
      .model_powerdown(model_powerdown),
      .mcg(model_powerdown),
      .lambda(_lambda[i])
      );
  assign fnl_verifier_lock = (tx_ready & rx_ready) ? &verifier_lock :1'b0;

native_my_ip native_my_inst
 (
  .tx_analogreset(tx_analogreset),
 //.unused_tx_parallel_data({1536{1'b0}})

  );

// END Section I

resync
 #(
   .INIT_VALUE (1)
   ) inst_reset_sync
   (
.clk    (tx_coreclkin),
.reset  (!tx_ready), // tx_digitalreset from reset
.d      (1'b0),
.q      (srst_tx_common  )
);

har HA2  (fs, ha, lf, c);                  

#need to extract xuvs
xuvs or1(fcarry_out, half_carry_2, half_carry_1);
```

**expected output**

```
model_ip
native_my_ip
resync
har
xuvs
```

**code.py**

```
import re

input_file = open("sample.log", "r")
lines = input_file.read()   # reads all lines and store into a variable
input_file.close()
for m in re.finditer(r'^\s*([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)\s+([a-zA-Z_0-9]+\s+\(|#\()',   lines, re.MULTILINE):
   print m.group(1)
```

Comment: Change `\s+\(` to `\s*\(`

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/svdM2P/1/. Also, consider `^\s*(\w+)\s+(\w+|#)\s*\(`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/svdM2P/2) ([Python demo](https://ideone.com/W3uiTY)).

Comment: If my answer works for you please consider upvoting/accepting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to match any optional whitespace chars before the `(`:

```
^\s*(\w+)\s+(\w+|#)\s*\(
                   ^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/svdM2P/2). The `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` can  be shortened to `\w` (if you need to use it in Python 3 and only match ASCII letters and digits, compile with `re.ASCII` flag).

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line (since `re.MULTILINE` is used)
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more letters, digits or `_`
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(\w+|#)` - Group 2: one or more letters, digits or `_` or a `#`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\(`  - a `(` char.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/W3uiTY):

```
for m in re.finditer(r'^\s*(\w+)\s+(\w+|#)\s*\(',   lines, re.MULTILINE):
    print m.group(1)
```

Output:

```
model_ip
native_my_ip
resync
har
xuvs
```